# Calling parent functions from child component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following structure.

**ParentComponent.ts**

```js
reset(offense) {
    return this.http.post(...);
}
```

**ParentComponent.html**

```html
<ion-list>
    <swipable-offense-card
        *ngFor="let offense of filteredOffenses"
        [offense]="offense"
        (onReset)="reset(offense)"
        >
    </swipable-offense-card>
</ion-list>
```

and child:
**ChildComponent.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'swipable-offense-card',
    templateUrl: 'swipable-offense-card.html',
  })
  export class SwipableOffenseCard {
    @Input() offense: Offense;
    @Output() onReset: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    reset() {
      this.onReset.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent.html**

```html
<p>{{ offense.title }}</p>
<button (click)="reset()"></button>
```

Right now, with this structure, the offense parameter that I pass here `(onReset)="reset(offense)"` is being sent to the parent component. However, I prefer doing something like this.

**ChildComponent.ts**

```js
reset() {
    this.onReset.emit({
       ...this.offense
    });
}
```

however this one doesn't send any parameters to reset method of parent component. How I can do it in Angular?

Comment: <pre>reset() {
    this.onReset.emit({
       ...this.offense
    });
}</pre> with this structure .Your parent function is triggering ? (never mind parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `$event` in parameter like this

```
// ParentComponent.html
<ion-list>
  <swipable-offense-card
     *ngFor="let offense of filteredOffenses"
     [offense]="offense"
     (onReset)="reset($event)"
     >
 </swipable-offense-card>
</ion-list>
```

Here is the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkfxb2